# Maven Resource Plugin Copying Files

Tags: maven

I currently have some Maven projects which when I install the project I need to copy all files from the conf folder to the target folder.

```
|-Project
    |--src
    |--conf <--FROM HERE -->
    |--lib
    |--target <--TO HERE-->
```

I have attempted this in the pom.xml to no avail. What am I doing wrong? My plugin part of the pom.xml is below:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/conf</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you copy the resources in the phase `install`. In that phase your target archive is already built and copied to your local repository. See the [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). You'll propably want to do it in the `process-resources` phase.

Comment: I have actually managed to just solve this by removing the <include>*</include> tag. I dont know why but it works :) now Im just trying to delete some files using the maven-clean-plugin. I am able to delete all or none but not specific ones for some reason. I am also trying to do this in the install phase