# Take post-build action maven

Tags: maven

I want to sftp the binary generated after build (if build is successful) is completed to a different server using maven. Please suggest how this can be done?

I want to edit pom.xml to achieve this.

Build system is maven. Please not that file is to be copied on different server

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Resource Plugin Copying Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423781/maven-resource-plugin-copying-files)

Comment: @arghtype - The one you are talking about is copying files to same server. I want to copy it on different

Answer (score 1):

You typically described a perfect use case for the [Wagon Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/).